# css and image sprites

Tags: html, css, http, image, css-sprites

I got a quick question about sprites in css:
Will I send two HTTP Request if I include the same image twice in a css file? For example if I want to load two different buttons from the same icon set image:

```
.btn-1 {
    background:url('img/icons.png') 0 0;
}

.btn-2 {
    background:url('img/icons.png') 0 -60px;
}
```

or is there another way to only include the image once?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The browser will cache the image so the 2nd time its fetched from cache.

But what you want to do in a situation like this is to let CSS do its job.
If those buttons are `<a>` for example.

```
a {
    background: url('img/icons.png');
}

.btn-1 {
    background-position:0 0;
}

.btn-2 {
    background-position: 0 -60px;
}
```

Comment: In other words: you still have the _potential_ for two requests, but in practice the browser is smart enough to avoid them.

Comment: That looks good, Youtube uses a similar method where they include the sprite in a css class called "master-sprite", then each time they need an icon/image they call that css class.

Answer (score 4):

Besides that what Ólafur said, you could also rewrite your CSS that the URI reference will only occur once:

```
.btn-1,
.btn-2 {
    background:url('img/icons.png') 0 0;
}
.btn-2 {
    background-position: 0 -60px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes but the client should receive a HTTP 304

> 304 Not Modified
>   If the client has performed a conditional GET request and access is allowed, but the document has not been modified, the server SHOULD respond with this status code. The 304 response MUST NOT contain a message-body, and thus is always terminated by the first empty line after the header fields.

So the image will not be send twice but used from cache instead.

[HTTP/1.1: Status Code Definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.5)

Comment: No, each image will only be requested once per page.